# Calculate Price x input value x input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a function where my visitors can calculate the price for having their apartment cleaned (for a cleaning company). So my question is how I would go about having two input fields (one for the size of apartment and one for the number of times per month) and multiply that with a price. Lets say the price is $10. So I need to multiply $10 x input field 1 x input field 2 = Total Price.

Someone who could give some guidence on how to make this. I'm quite new at this but I guess its quite basic even though I haven't managed to find a good answer elsewhere. Thanks alot in advance!

Update: This is what I managed to get working (with the help of another answer)

```
<input id="a1" type="text" />
<input id="a2" type="text" onblur="calculate()"  />
<input id="a3" type="text" name="total_amt" />
<script>
    calculate = function() {
        var resources = document.getElementById('a1').value;
        var minutes = document.getElementById('a2').value; 
        document.getElementById('a3').value = parseInt(resources)*parseInt(minutes);
    }
</script>
```

But I need to multiply the two input fields with, lets say $10 (which is not visible to the visitor). And also have a "submit" button or when pressed enter it shows the result in the third field. When I now press enter the result show but quickly dissappears.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: Kindly send the code what you have tried.

Comment: if you are really new to javascript, try w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope this the solution you need

```
<script>
calculate = function()
{
var price=10;
var resources = document.getElementById('a1').value;
var minutes = document.getElementById('a2').value; 
document.getElementById('a3').value = price*parseInt(resources)*parseInt(minutes);
}
</script>
```